# find + print the files with time stamp

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression

the following find syntax will print the files that old then 10 day

```
find  /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector  -type f -mtime +10 -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -print
/var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/collector-gc.log-201808130951
/var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/collector-gc.log-201808130403
/var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/gc.log-201808011229
/var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/collector-gc.log-201808011229
/var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/gc.log-201808091332
```

what need to add to my syntax in order to print the following example 
so time stamp will be before the file path

```
2018 Aug 28 14:20   /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/collector-gc.log-201808130951
2018 Aug 28 12:12   /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/collector-gc.log-201808130403
2018 Aug 28 14:32   /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/gc.log-201808011229
2018 Aug 28 14:32   /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/collector-gc.log-201808011229
2018 Aug 28 11:22   /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector/gc.log-201808091332
```

Comment: Note you could use the `-ls` in place of the `-print` in your `find` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU `find`, use `-printf format` instead of `-print`. For example:

```
find /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector -type f -mtime +10 -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -printf '%TY %Tb %Td %TH:%TM %p\n'
```

The first letter — «type» of the time:

- `%T` — modification time.
- `%C` — creation time.
- `%A` — access time.

The second letter (i.e. right after the «type» of the time) is the field from `strftime()`/`date` to show.

Note that `-mtime +10` finds files that are over **11** days old, not 10 (whose age, rounded down to an integer number of days is *stricktly* greater than 10).

Also note that `-regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$'` would match on a `foo.login/file.tar.bz2` file for instance. You might as well use the standard `-name '*.log*[0-9]'` which would be a bit stricter (would still match on `file.login.tar.bz2`).

Comment: the problem is that the printf print not print the full path  of each file as "2018 Aug 13 04:20 gc.log-201808130403"  , can you please update the answer so full path will printed ?

Comment: replace `%P` with `%p`